# On the default/fill value for outer joins

Tags: python, pandas

Below are teeny/toy versions of much larger/complex dataframes I'm working with:

```
>>> A
  key         u         v         w         x
0   a  0.757954  0.258917  0.404934  0.303313
1   b  0.583382  0.504687       NaN  0.618369
2   c       NaN  0.982785  0.902166       NaN
3   d  0.898838  0.472143       NaN  0.610887
4   e  0.966606  0.865310       NaN  0.548699
5   f       NaN  0.398824  0.668153       NaN

>>> B
  key         y         z
0   a  0.867603       NaN
1   b       NaN  0.191067
2   c  0.238616  0.803179
3   p  0.080446       NaN
4   q  0.932834       NaN
5   r  0.706561  0.814467
```

(FWIW, at the end of this post, I provide code to generate these dataframes.)

I want to produce an outer join of these dataframes on the `key` column<sup>1</sup>, in such a way that the new positions induced by the outer join get default value 0.0.  IOW, the desired result looks like this

```
  key         u         v         w         x         y         z
0   a  0.757954  0.258917  0.404934  0.303313  0.867603       NaN
1   b  0.583382  0.504687       NaN  0.618369       NaN  0.191067
2   c       NaN  0.982785  0.902166       NaN  0.238616  0.803179
3   d  0.898838  0.472143       NaN  0.610887  0.000000  0.000000
4   e  0.966606   0.86531       NaN  0.548699  0.000000  0.000000
5   f       NaN  0.398824  0.668153       NaN  0.000000  0.000000
6   p  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.080446       NaN
7   q  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.932834       NaN
8   r  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.706561  0.814467
```

(Note that this desired output contains some NaNs, namely those that were already present in `A` or `B`.)

The `merge` method gets me part-way there, but the filled-in default values are NaN's, not 0.0's:

```
>>> C = pandas.DataFrame.merge(A, B, how='outer', on='key')
>>> C
  key         u         v         w         x         y         z
0   a  0.757954  0.258917  0.404934  0.303313  0.867603       NaN
1   b  0.583382  0.504687       NaN  0.618369       NaN  0.191067
2   c       NaN  0.982785  0.902166       NaN  0.238616  0.803179
3   d  0.898838  0.472143       NaN  0.610887       NaN       NaN
4   e  0.966606  0.865310       NaN  0.548699       NaN       NaN
5   f       NaN  0.398824  0.668153       NaN       NaN       NaN
6   p       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.080446       NaN
7   q       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.932834       NaN
8   r       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.706561  0.814467
```

The `fillna` method fails to produce the desired output, because it modifies some positions that should be left unchanged:

```
>>> C.fillna(0.0)
  key         u         v         w         x         y         z
0   a  0.757954  0.258917  0.404934  0.303313  0.867603  0.000000
1   b  0.583382  0.504687  0.000000  0.618369  0.000000  0.191067
2   c  0.000000  0.982785  0.902166  0.000000  0.238616  0.803179
3   d  0.898838  0.472143  0.000000  0.610887  0.000000  0.000000
4   e  0.966606  0.865310  0.000000  0.548699  0.000000  0.000000
5   f  0.000000  0.398824  0.668153  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
6   p  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.080446  0.000000
7   q  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.932834  0.000000
8   r  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.706561  0.814467
```

How can I achieve the desired output efficiently?  (Performance matters here, because I intend to perform this operation on much larger dataframes than those shown here.)

---

FWIW, below is the code to generate the example dataframes `A` and `B`.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from collections import OrderedDict
from random import random, seed

def make_dataframe(rows, colnames):
    return DataFrame(OrderedDict([(n, [row[i] for row in rows])
                                 for i, n in enumerate(colnames)]))

maybe_nan = lambda: float('nan') if random() < 0.4 else random()

seed(0)

A = make_dataframe([['a', maybe_nan(), maybe_nan(), maybe_nan(), maybe_nan()],
                    ['b', maybe_nan(), maybe_nan(), maybe_nan(), maybe_nan()],
                    ['c', maybe_nan(), maybe_nan(), maybe_nan(), maybe_nan()],
                    ['d', maybe_nan(), maybe_nan(), maybe_nan(), maybe_nan()],
                    ['e', maybe_nan(), maybe_nan(), maybe_nan(), maybe_nan()],
                    ['f', maybe_nan(), maybe_nan(), maybe_nan(), maybe_nan()]],
                   ('key', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x'))

B = make_dataframe([['a', maybe_nan(), maybe_nan()],
                    ['b', maybe_nan(), maybe_nan()],
                    ['c', maybe_nan(), maybe_nan()],
                    ['p', maybe_nan(), maybe_nan()],
                    ['q', maybe_nan(), maybe_nan()],
                    ['r', maybe_nan(), maybe_nan()]],
                   ('key', 'y', 'z'))
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For for case of *multi-key* outer joins, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39751636/559827).</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fill zeros after the `merge`:

```
res = pd.merge(A, B, how="outer")
res.loc[~res.key.isin(A.key), A.columns] = 0
```

**EDIT**

to skip `key` column:

```
res.loc[~res.key.isin(A.key), A.columns.drop("key")] = 0
```

Comment: Question: how would one generalize this solution to the case where the merge is on multiple columns, e.g. `merge(..., on=('key1', 'key2', ...), ...)`?

Comment: I have no idea, you can't know what's the join columns after calling `merge()`.

Comment: If you use private operation, you can get the information: `mo = pd.tools.merge._MergeOperation(A, B, how="outer"); print(mo.left_on)`

Comment: Thanks...  It looks like I simplified my example too much.  In the real-life situation I'm working with, I'm actually merging on multiple keys.  Only now I realize that this is an aspect of the problem I should have kept in my example...