# On the default/fill value for *multi-key* outer joins

Tags: python, pandas

NB: The post below is the "multi-key" counterpart of an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39748976/559827) of mine.  The solutions to that earlier question work only for the case where the join is on a single key, and it is not clear to me how to generalize those solutions to the multi-key case presented below.  Since, IME, modifying an already-answered question in a way that disqualifies the answers it has received is frowned upon in SO, I'm posting this variant separately.  I have also posted a [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335424/559827) to Meta SO on whether I should delete this post and instead modify the original question, at the expense of invalidating its current answers.

---

Below are teeny/toy versions of much larger/complex dataframes I'm working with:

```
>>> A
  key1 key2         u         v         w         x
0    a    G  0.757954  0.258917  0.404934  0.303313
1    b    H  0.583382  0.504687       NaN  0.618369
2    c    I       NaN  0.982785  0.902166       NaN
3    d    J  0.898838  0.472143       NaN  0.610887
4    e    K  0.966606  0.865310       NaN  0.548699
5    f    L       NaN  0.398824  0.668153       NaN

  key1 key2         y         z
0    a    G  0.867603       NaN
1    b    H       NaN  0.191067
2    c    I  0.238616  0.803179
3    d    G  0.080446       NaN
4    e    H  0.932834       NaN
5    f    I  0.706561  0.814467
```

(FWIW, at the end of this post, I provide code to generate these dataframes.)

I want to produce an outer join of these dataframes on the `key1` and `key2` columns, in such a way that the new positions induced by the outer join get default value 0.0.  IOW, the desired result looks like this

```
  key1 key2         u         v         w         x          y         z
0    a    G  0.757954  0.258917  0.404934  0.303313   0.867603       NaN
1    b    H  0.583382  0.504687       NaN  0.618369        NaN  0.191067
2    c    I       NaN  0.982785  0.902166       NaN   0.238616  0.803179
3    d    J  0.898838  0.472143       NaN  0.610887   0.000000  0.000000
4    e    K  0.966606   0.86531       NaN  0.548699   0.000000  0.000000
5    f    L       NaN  0.398824  0.668153       NaN   0.000000  0.000000
6    d    G  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   0.080446       NaN
7    e    H  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   0.932834       NaN
8    f    I  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   0.706561  0.814467
```

(Note that this desired output contains some NaNs, namely those that were already present in `A` or `B`.)

The `merge` method gets me part-way there, but the filled-in default values are NaN's, not 0.0's:

```
>>> C = pandas.DataFrame.merge(A, B, how='outer', on=('key1', 'key2'))
>>> C
  key1 key2         u         v         w         x         y         z
0    a    G  0.757954  0.258917  0.404934  0.303313  0.867603       NaN
1    b    H  0.583382  0.504687       NaN  0.618369       NaN  0.191067
2    c    I       NaN  0.982785  0.902166       NaN  0.238616  0.803179
3    d    J  0.898838  0.472143       NaN  0.610887       NaN       NaN
4    e    K  0.966606  0.865310       NaN  0.548699       NaN       NaN
5    f    L       NaN  0.398824  0.668153       NaN       NaN       NaN
6    d    G       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.080446       NaN
7    e    H       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.932834       NaN
8    f    I       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.706561  0.814467
```

The `fillna` method fails to produce the desired output, because it modifies some positions that should be left unchanged:

```
>>> C.fillna(0.0)
  key1 key2         u         v         w         x         y         z
0    a    G  0.757954  0.258917  0.404934  0.303313  0.867603  0.000000
1    b    H  0.583382  0.504687  0.000000  0.618369  0.000000  0.191067
2    c    I  0.000000  0.982785  0.902166  0.000000  0.238616  0.803179
3    d    J  0.898838  0.472143  0.000000  0.610887  0.000000  0.000000
4    e    K  0.966606  0.865310  0.000000  0.548699  0.000000  0.000000
5    f    L  0.000000  0.398824  0.668153  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
6    d    G  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.080446  0.000000
7    e    H  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.932834  0.000000
8    f    I  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.706561  0.814467
```

How can I achieve the desired output efficiently?  (Performance matters here, because I intend to perform this operation on much larger dataframes than those shown here.)

---

**IMPORTANT:** In order to keep the example minimal, I made the multikey consist of only two columns; in practice the number of keys in a multi-key may be significantly greater.  Proposed answers should be suitable for multi-keys consisting of at least half-dozen columns.

---

FWIW, below is the code to generate the example dataframes `A` and `B`.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from collections import OrderedDict
from random import random, seed

def make_dataframe(rows, colnames):
    return DataFrame(OrderedDict([(n, [row[i] for row in rows])
                                 for i, n in enumerate(colnames)]))

maybe_nan = lambda: float('nan') if random() < 0.4 else random()

seed(0)

A = make_dataframe([['A', 'g', maybe_nan(), maybe_nan(), maybe_nan(), maybe_nan()],
                    ['B', 'h', maybe_nan(), maybe_nan(), maybe_nan(), maybe_nan()],
                    ['C', 'i', maybe_nan(), maybe_nan(), maybe_nan(), maybe_nan()],
                    ['D', 'j', maybe_nan(), maybe_nan(), maybe_nan(), maybe_nan()],
                    ['E', 'k', maybe_nan(), maybe_nan(), maybe_nan(), maybe_nan()],
                    ['F', 'l', maybe_nan(), maybe_nan(), maybe_nan(), maybe_nan()]],
                   ('key1', 'key2', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x'))

B = make_dataframe([['A', 'g', maybe_nan(), maybe_nan()],
                    ['B', 'h', maybe_nan(), maybe_nan()],
                    ['C', 'i', maybe_nan(), maybe_nan()],
                    ['D', 'g', maybe_nan(), maybe_nan()],
                    ['E', 'h', maybe_nan(), maybe_nan()],
                    ['F', 'i', maybe_nan(), maybe_nan()]],
                   ('key1', 'key2', 'y', 'z'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `keys` to be the index of the two `DF's`:

```
def index_set(frame, keys=['key1', 'key2']):
    frame.set_index(keys, inplace=True)
    return frame
```

Subset the `DF's` containing `NaN` values:

```
def nulls(frame):
    nulls_in_frame = frame[frame.isnull().any(axis=1)].reset_index()
    return nulls_in_frame
```

Join the two `Df's`. Concatenate the joined `DF` with each of the subset of `NaN` containing `DF's` and drop the duplicated values filling the remaining `NaN` left with 0's.

Then, using `combine_first` to patch the values using chaining operation with the joined `DF`.

```
def perform_join(fr_1, fr_2, keys=['key1', 'key2']):
    fr_1 = index_set(fr_1); frame_2 = index_set(fr_2)
    frame = fr_1.join(fr_2, how='outer').reset_index()
    cat_fr_1 = pd.concat([frame, nulls(fr_1)]).drop_duplicates(keys, keep=False).fillna(0)
    cat_fr_2 = pd.concat([frame, nulls(fr_2)]).drop_duplicates(keys, keep=False).fillna(0)
    fr_1_join = frame.combine_first(frame.fillna(cat_fr_1[fr_1.columns]))
    joined_frame = fr_1_join.combine_first(frame.fillna(cat_fr_2[fr_2.columns]))
    return joined_frame
```

Finally,

```
perform_join(A, B)
```

[image]